# 共有フォルダを作ろうとしてvagrant up ができなくなった

Tags: vagrant

共有ファイルを作ろうとして
vagrantfileにこのような設定をしました。

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/main", "c:/work/main", type:"rsync", rsync__exclude: [".git/", "node_modules"]
  config.vm.synced_folder "/main/public", "c:/work/main/public"
```

すると次からvagrant  upをすると

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: /main
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: /main/public
```

このようなエラーが出るようになってしまい。
サーバーが立ち上がらなくなってしまいました。
何かわかるかたがいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `/main` 及び `/main/public` というディレクトリはホストOSに存在しますか？

Comment: フォルダを追加は存在している状況です、、

Answer (score 0):

`config.vm.synced_folder` のパラメータで、ホストOS(Vagrantを実行しているWindows)のパスとゲストOS(作成されるVM)のパスの順番が逆になっているように見えます。

パラメータの順番を入れ替えてエラーが解消されるかご確認ください。